# how to fix time or distance interval for startLocationUpdatesAsync while using expo?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I use startLocationUpdatesAsync in my expo app to track users location in the background.

I want to read data about locations I need geofencing for from Firebase, and I want to check if a user visited that location already (I also read that from Firebase).

The problem is I read from Firebase too many times for short period of time and I am afraid that it will be costly.

Is there a way to fix time or distance interval for running this background task? Or if there is some other way to deal with this kind of problem?

I already used deferredUpdatesDistance, deferredUpdatesInterval, distanceInterval and timeInterval. It doesn't seem to work with expo go app or Android build

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add enough code so that others can reproduce your issue. Check out [ask] when you can.

Comment: Please refer this - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9288